# Twitter search API with location

Tags: c#, twitter

I want to execute a Location-based Twitter search using the location operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the geocode parameter referenced here: http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-Search-API-Method:-search

Or you can use the near parameter referenced here: http://search.twitter.com/operators